# xcodebuild - Error Domain=IDECapabilitiesErrorDomain Code=1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, ios-app-extension

I am archiving one iOS app through common line, xcodebuild. My app is using a group, `group.app.com` and also an widget. My profiles are OK both for debug and release. But I find a weird issue in the terminal.

Archive command,

```
xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme App archive -archivePath ~/autobuild/output/App.xcarchive -configuration Release
```

Error:

> Details:  Failed to expand identifiers "{(
>       "group.com.app" )}": Error Domain=IDECapabilitiesErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation requires a selected developer portal team."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation requires a selected
>   developer portal team., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you selected a team in the settings of each target in the workspace?

Comment: Provisioning Profile, Team and Signing Certificate are set. They is no error in Xcode settings.

Comment: Does creating the app and all other targets with Xcode instead of `xcodebuild` works as expected?

Comment: yes its working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this with my builds as well, and it appears to be a bug with xcodebuild: [discussed in this devforums post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63625). According to one of the posters there, his radar was closed as a duplicate, so we at least know that Apple is aware of the issue and agrees that it is a bug. I'd recommend filing your own radar as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info